# Force property order in Spring Data MongoDB mapping

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a Location object that I need to force the order of the properties when they get persisted to mongodb, but I'm not having much luck figuring out how to do it.  The Location class looks something like:

```
Location {
   float lat;
   float lon;
   County county;
}
```

When it get's persisted into mongo, county is always before lat and lon.  This is a problem because I'm trying to put a geoindex on it and the first two properties must be lat/long.

I have tried:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="location")
@XmlType(propOrder={"latitude", "longitude", "county"})
Location {
   float lat;
   float lon;
   County county;
}
```

That works when the location object is serialized to xml to my client, but not to the DB.  It seems that spring data or some mongo mapper is always doing things in alphabetical order.

Does anyone know how to force the order properties get persisted into mongo?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the @Field annotation's order attribute to force field order. So, if you have:

```
Location {
   @Field(order = 1)
   float lat;

   @Field(order = 2)
   float lon;

   @Field(order = 3)
   County county;
}
```

the fields are persisted in the following order: lat, lon, county.

Comment: This was the fix committed for the issue I submitted so I'll accept your answer.  Thanks for updating it!  I actually ended up doing something different which I'll add.

Answer (score 1):

Just so everyone knows, I've been talking with the Spring developers and they asked me to submit a JIRA for the issue because there is no way to do this right now.  The JIRA can be found here:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATADOC-172

Comment: Should be fixed with the latest nightly snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are using to convert from your POJOs to MongoDB. Mappers like Morphia (http://code.google.com/p/morphia) will use the field order as declared in your class. There are options to control this as well in various ways.

If this is a Spring Data (framework) issue I would suggest heading to their forums for support.

Comment: Yes, it is using Spring Data (as stated in the title), and tried there, but no responses yet so wanted to try my luck on stackoverflow.  Thanks

Comment: I'd be interested how Morphia implements the "field order as declared in your class" as the JavaDoc for Class.getFields() explicitly does *not* guarantee a certain ordering. So one might get different order of fields on different VMs and shouldn't even rely on the order being persistent for a single VM.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I ended up making a Point object that contains the lat/long and indexed that object.  That way, it was the only thing in the object and the order didn't matter.

On a related note, just today I learned if you are are going to want to do spatial queries, you MUST store your properties in the following order: Longitude, Latitude.  You can see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/) for more info, but I banged my head against the wall with this for a while today, so if you are storing points for geo queries, make sure you have them in the right order.  All this means is you put longitude first in your class.  I suppose you could annotate them with the @Field attribute as well.